# Update TABLE with INNER JOIN the multi-part identifier could not be bound update inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a SQL statement that performs an update with two tables. I have tried with the SELECT statement, and it is working, but with update I get an error:

> the multi-part identifier could not be bound update

```
SELECT cIntrodRefCode, iPayerCompanyID, cIntrodEmail, bGSTApply, *
FROM tblIntroducer
INNER JOIN tblEntity
    ON tblIntroducer.iIntroducerID = tblEntity.iEntityRootID
WHERE cIntrodRefCode = '4'
```

Update statement not working it shows:

> the multi-part identifier could not be bound update

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.bGSTApply = 1, t1.cIntrodEmail = 'michaelc@gorapid.com.au', t2.iPayerCompanyID = 7
FROM tblIntroducer AS t1
    INNER JOIN tblEntity AS t2
    ON t1.iIntroducerID = t2.iEntityRootID
WHERE t1.cIntrodRefCode = '4'
```

I have also tried this one but it also shows the same error

```
UPDATE tblIntroducer
SET tblIntroducer.bGSTApply = 1, tblIntroducer.cIntrodEmail = 'michaelc@gorapid.com.au', tblEntity.iPayerCompanyID = 7
FROM tblIntroducer
INNER JOIN tblEntity 
    ON tblIntroducer.iIntroducerID = tblEntity.iEntityRootID
WHERE tblIntroducer.cIntrodRefCode = '4'
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: You execute `UPDATE tblIntroducer` (i.e. update one table) but try to set the value into another table which produces an error. You need in 2nd UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE t1
SET t1.bGSTApply = 1, t1.cIntrodEmail = 'michaelc@gorapid.com.au'
FROM tblIntroducer AS t1
INNER JOIN tblEntity AS t2 ON t1.iIntroducerID = t2.iEntityRootID
WHERE t1.cIntrodRefCode = '4'

go

UPDATE t2
SET t2.iPayerCompanyID = 7
FROM tblIntroducer AS t1
INNER JOIN tblEntity AS t2 ON t1.iIntroducerID = t2.iEntityRootID
WHERE t1.cIntrodRefCode = '4'
```

you can update one table in every update with join